# StatusBar Notofication Plugin for phonegap shows error

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to send some push notifications to the statusbar on Android using phone gap.

I used this [plugin](https://github.com/saileshmittal/phonegap-system-notification-plugin/tree/master/android-statusbar-notificaion), but when I run the application it shows this error: cordona cannot be resolved.

Any ideas on how can I fix it ?

Comment: What version of PhoneGap are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that plugin hasn't been updated for 2.0.0. You are probably better off with this version https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification